# new TextWatcher nullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext, textwatcher

My app currently have multiple views and layouts, I'm using swipe-view design and i have an
"EditText" box inside a view which is not the main view.

Now I'm trying to set a new TextWatcher for that EditText box and if I'm trying to this in
"OnCreate" I get nullPointerException.

Though if I assign this action to one of the buttons placed in my main activity it works just
fine, so I don't know what to do to set that TextWatcher as soon as the app launches.

```
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText1)).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText2)).setText("try");
        }
    });
```

And here is the "OnCreate":

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    compPagerAdapter = new compSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.comp);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);


    compViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.ScreenPager);
    compViewPager.setAdapter(compPagerAdapter);;
    compViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(mMainPagerListener);


    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText1)).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText2)).setText("0000");
        }
    });

}
```

And the LogCat:

```
    09-27 14:38:15.988: E/AndroidRuntime(8179): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-27 14:38:15.988: E/AndroidRuntime(8179): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.casio/com.example.casio.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-27 14:38:15.988: E/AndroidRuntime(8179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
09-27 14:38:15.988: E/AndroidRuntime(8179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-27 14:38:15.988: E/AndroidRuntime(8179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-27 14:38:15.988: E/AndroidRuntime(8179):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-27 14:38:15.988: E/AndroidRuntime(8179):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-27 14:38:15.988: E/AndroidRuntime(8179):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-27 14:38:15.988: E/AndroidRuntime(8179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-27 14:38:15.988: E/AndroidRuntime(8179):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-27 14:38:15.988: E/AndroidRuntime(8179):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-27 14:38:15.988: E/AndroidRuntime(8179):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-27 14:38:15.988: E/AndroidRuntime(8179):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-27 14:38:15.988: E/AndroidRuntime(8179):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-27 14:38:15.988: E/AndroidRuntime(8179): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-27 14:38:15.988: E/AndroidRuntime(8179):     at com.example.casio.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:73)
09-27 14:38:15.988: E/AndroidRuntime(8179):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
09-27 14:38:15.988: E/AndroidRuntime(8179):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-27 14:38:15.988: E/AndroidRuntime(8179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
09-27 14:38:15.988: E/AndroidRuntime(8179):     ... 11 more
```

The problematic line is:

```
 ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText1)).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
```

I assume this has something to do with the layout creation or something like that but I can't get it to work.

Comment: post your onCreate method. Is it possible that you assign the TextWatcher before your view was inflated? Where exactly is NPE happening?

Comment: The exception is generated at line 73

`09-27 14:38:15.988: E/AndroidRuntime(8179): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-27 14:38:15.988: E/AndroidRuntime(8179):     at com.example.casio.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:73)`
Could you show us which line is that?

Comment: ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText1)).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {